# Average of Numbers in Javascript/Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I have a json response where have to calculate the average of "**throughput_kbps**" where protocol name is "**TCP**" for each result array.

I using Javascript/Angularjs for this

Please refer [This json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openstack/vmtp/master/doc/source/_static/example.json)

Thanx in advance

Comment: filter the results for "TCP", pluck the throughput_kbps of that set, sum the set, divide by the count of the set.

Comment: Are you using underscorejs?

Comment: @dandavis Thanx but Any sample example for this ?

Comment: @DivakarDass no .. Using Angularjs only

Comment: `fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openstack/vmtp/master/doc/source/_static/example.json")
.then(x=>x.json()).then(x=>x.flows.map(y=>y.results.filter(k=>k.protocol=="TCP")))
.then(r=>r.reduce((a,b)=>a.concat(b)))
.then(x=>[x.length,x.map(y=>y.throughput_kbps)])
.then(x=>[x[0], x[1].reduce((a,b)=>+a+ +b)])
.then(r=>r[1]/r[0])
.then(alert)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var len1 = obj['flows'].length;
for (var i=0; i<len1; i++) 
{
   var tmp = obj.['flows'][i];
   var len2 = tmp.['results'].length;
   var mean = 0;
   for (var j=0; j<len2; ++j)
   {
      var tmpResult = tmp.['results'][j];
      if (tmpResult['protocol'] === 'TCP')
         mean += tmpResult['throughput_kbps'];
   }
   console.log(mean);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var sum = 0;
var count = 0;

data.flows.map(function(d){
    return d.results.filter(function(res){
        if(res.protocol == 'TCP'){
            sum += res.throughput_kbps;
            count++;
            return sum;
        }
    })
});

var avg = sum/count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your JSON as an argument to this function. This'll return you the average throughput you ask for.

```
function calculateThroughput(json){
 var flowsObj = json.flows;
 var throughputSum = 0;
 var noOfSamples = 0;

 for(noOfFlows in flowsObj){
    var resultObj = flowsObj[noOfFlows].results;
    for(noOfResults in resultObj){
        if(resultObj[noOfResults].protocol == "TCP"){
            throughputSum += resultObj[noOfResults].throughput_kbps;
            noOfSamples++;
        }
    }
 }
 return (throughputSum/noOfSamples);
};
```

Hope this helps.